# What does IN mean in Windows device driver functions?

Tags: c, windows, device-driver

I'm starting to learn how to program Windows drivers but can't seem to find anywhere that contains the definition of IN located in the argument declarations of functions. For example:

```
NTSTATUS DriverEntry( IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, 
                      IN PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
```

Could someone please explain what IN means?

Comment: It's an annotation. In reality it's definition is probably nothing. It's used to help code analysis tools.

Comment: That the parameter is an input only. It can be used for some optimisations, but it's probably defined to be nothing and thus is there simply as documentation.

Comment: I haven't  checked, but it would be nice if it expanded to `const`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, it is defined as follows:

```
///
/// Datum is passed to the function.
///
#define IN
```

This is used to indicate that the parameter is an input parameter only.

As `OUT`  and `OPTIONAL` is used to indicate output and optional parameters.

These are maybe for convenience.

Comment: Such annotations are also used to aid static analysis, not just for convenience.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Alexey, i was not aware of static analysis.

Answer (score 4):

These are called SAL (Source Annotation Language) annotations and there is [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182032.aspx) on how to use them to benefit from great static analysis.

The actual syntax may differ from one SAL version to another (e.g. IN and _In_). There's backwards compatibility, but I recommend using the latest syntax consistently.

Answer (score 0):

In the WDK this is defined in the ntdef.h file.  Normally in your drivers you would just include the ntddk.h or wdm.h files, which will in turn include ntdef.h and other important header files.  For example:

```
#include <ntddk.h>
```

As mentioned above, this annotation is used for static analysis and is simply defined as

```
#define IN
```